# Oracle text search using .Net and Devart's dotConnect for Oracle

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, ef-code-first, dotconnect, oracle-text

We have a web application that needs to search across all tables using a keyword. I have not found much on Google other than using a Linq query.

We need the search to be performed by Oracle, not the web application.

Has anyone found a solution to using this method? 
The view of the Oracle database we have requires us to use dotConnect for Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

The Oracle Text functionality is supported in the latest version of dotConnect for Oracle. 
For more information, please take a look at [Using Oracle Full-Text Search in Entity Framework](http://blogs.devart.com/dotconnect/using-oracle-full-text-search-in-entity-framework.html) article.

Devart Team